# Several applications not lauching after upgrade (Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: gnome, 18.04, synaptic, dbus, 0ad

After upgrade to 18.04, several applications don't open anymore. Synapctic, SweetHome3d, the game 0ad, etc. Trying to launch it via terminal, 0ad, I got this:

```
dbus[2283]: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1362.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.

  D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

## Steam gaming bug

You appear to be affected by this bug reported on Github:

- [Arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect #5103](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5103)

which has been closed as a duplicate of this bug:

- [Thread synchronization object is unusable on Fedora 26 #5101](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5101)

and summarized in this bug:

- [Steam Client's SDL broken by XMODIFIERS #5201](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5201)

You should read all bug reports from top to bottom but to summarize a couple of solutions.

### Work-around from first link

> A workaround is to opt-out the beta and to restart the client:

```
mv ${HOME}/.local/share/Steam/package/beta ${HOME}/.local/share/Steam/package/beta.disabled
```

### Work-around from second link

> The dbus_message_new_method_call() message is non-fatal and the

```
ln -s ${HOME}/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 ${HOME}/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/pinned_libs_32/libdbus-1.so.3
```

> workaround from #5099 gets the steam client to start.

---

## Related bug you may or may not encounter

In the future you may also find yourself affected by this gaming bug: [D-Bus bug in 18.04 i386 SDL: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsdl2/+bug/1775067)

If so click on the link and subscribe to the bug. The more people reporting being affected by the bug the sooner it will be fixed.

In the meantime there are work-arounds posted by other users you can try.

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't help to solve the problem. The bug persists.

Comment: The problem with Synaptic is OK, it opens normally with Xorg (but not in Wayland). But when I try to upgrade ("do-release-upgrade") to 18.10, it wasn't possible because of i386 of my laptop... After many years I'm frustrated with Ubuntu.

Comment: You can probably pick up a used 10 year old 64-bit laptop with 2GHz processor and 4GB Ram with Windows Vista for about $100. That can run Ubuntu 18 but it won't be the fastest rig around but it will run 64-bit OS which most developers seem to prefer these days.

Comment: Well, if all the question was buy a new laptop, I wouldn't ask a thing here. But OK, thanks for the advice. I'm frustrated, after several years using Ubuntu-based and perceiving in it more bugs and slowness, I'm going try Manjaro now.